# SEO friendly URL error, some help me pls?

Tags: .htaccess, url, hyperlink, seo

I got an error with SEO linking..

this is what happens..

http://boznetwork.net/index.php?a=explore

If you click on a track (not the play button) but if you click on the title of the track. The orange load bar will not redirect you to the track page.

But if you open the track in a new tab then you will see the track.

What did I do wrong?

My *.htacess* file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f

RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]


RewriteRule index/a/(.*)/id/(.*)/ index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

and the links I changed it to:

```
<a href="'.$url.'/index/a/track/id/'.$row['track'].'/"
```

but before I changed the link it looked like this:

```
<a href="'.$url.'/index.php?a=track&id='.$row['track'].'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule is bogus. It always matches, then rewrites to exactly the same thing. This prevents the Apache from reaching the second rule.

Remove your first rule, and everything should work as expected.

Comment: If I delete this rule  RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]   then ai get 404 error.